# How can I retrieve different types of date in ios

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to create an app that can take date and time from user. Users with different locations can enter date according to their location timezone ie US, ASIA,GB etc..all they have different time formats so they will enter different date time formats, so how could I retrieve that string to date? Should I need to set date format each local time? Or is there any inbuilt functions in IOS  library so that allow a user to input different types of format date in textfield? Please help

```
NSString *datestring = self.date.text;
NSString *timestring = self.time.text;
NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", datestring, timestring];
```

This is how I get strings from user into textfield. Is there any other, better method?

Comment: you can use date formatter but the user may enter the date in there own way, so the date formate you specified could be deferent form the user, so adding date picker is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSDateFormatter to convert a date string to NSDate, and play with setLocal: and setDateFormat to appropriate date format.

For example: to use date formatter with current local setting of iDevice:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

Take a look at:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the [UIDatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006806) rather UITextField then you don't need to think about the locals.

Comment: Actullay i cant use datepicker here because of some reasons.